# currentTextChanged is triggered by default

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want to use the *currentTextChanged* signal to trigger only when i change something in a
ListWidget,like selecting an item.
But everytime i m running the script i got the first row "One", even if i do nothing(no click,etc).
I'm expecting no triggering for the first time.
Any reason for this behaviour?
I m using Pycharm, but i guess shouldn t matter.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QListWidget

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self):
      super().__init__()
      self.setWindowTitle("My App")
      widget = QListWidget()
      widget.addItems(["One", "Two", "Three"])
      widget.currentTextChanged.connect(self.text_changed) #triggering here

      self.setCentralWidget(widget)

  def text_changed(self, s): # s is a str
    print(s)
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec_()  # -> i expect to show nothing for the first time,instead is always "one"
```

Comment: Use [`itemChanged()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#itemChanged).

Comment: @musicamante itemSelectionChanged seems to work as expected, but i'm wondering why this behaviour.

Comment: I can answer that, but please clarify first what you meant by "when i change something in a ListWidget". That sentence would mean "any change in contents of the list", but you said that you used `itemSelectionChanged`, which is a very different thing. Please try to be more clear.

Comment: @musicamante i meant when i'm selecting an item from the list, for example.

Comment: Ok, for future reference, please try to be more specific and detailed in your questions: "change something" is a vague concept, and in item views would probably refer to contents change, item addition/removal, sorting, etc. In your case it was also completely misleading, since you were referring to the selection, which doesn't actually "change" *anything* to the view.

Comment: thanks, i ve changed it to be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, remember that the *selection* on an item view might not always match its *current index*. You can have a valid current index and *no* selection, or also have a valid selection that does *not* include the current index (which might also be invalid). Clicking on an item in a view *normally* changes both the selection *and* the current index, but that might not be always true.

Now, when a window is shown for the first time, it automatically tries to set the input focus on the first widget that can accept it.

When an item view receives focus for the first time, it automatically sets the current index to the first available (and selectable) index, if any exist.

The [`currentTextChanged()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#currentTextChanged) is "*emitted whenever the current item changes*", so, since you only have a widget (the list) and it also accepts focus, Qt will focus it when the window is first shown, resulting in a *current index change* and, thus, emitting the signal.

If you want to get notifications when the user actively changes the current index (the "selection"), then use [`itemSelectionChanged()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#itemSelectionChanged) or the related `selectionChanged` signal provided by the view's [`selectionModel()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#selectionModel).

Comment: so the focus is the issue here. thanks for the extensive explanation. Using widget.clearFocus() will do what i m expecting. And also adding other widget.

Comment: @Alexis No, `widget.clearFocus()` might not suffice: depending on the situation (and the OS), the window will still try to set the focus on the first available widget that accepts focus. If you are not planning on having any other widgets in that window, then use `self.setFocus()` instead.

Comment: focus is so weird. in the above script the hasFocus() is False, but if i set the       widget.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus) is working as i m expected. i guess i must study a bit the focus

Comment: There's nothing weird: the focus indicates that a widget can receive input events. If a widget is not visible, it cannot have focus: widgets can get focus only when shown, if you're calling `widget.hasFocus()` in the `__init__` you will always get `False`, since, obviously, you cannot click or type anything to a *non-visible* widget. Calling `setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)` *prevents* the widget from receiving focus (which is what happens when the window is shown, as explained in my answer).